# Web.config IIS rewrite rule to ignore specific file

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have a site txt map sitemaphttp.txt on my site. I redirect all my traffic to HTTPS. I still want  Google to be able to read this sitemap, so it won't read it from `https://example.com/sitemaphttp.txt` but from `http://example.com/sitemaphttp.txt`.  What rewrite rule I need to add to web.config so it will ignore all the other rules and just let that specific file through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To link to a custom site-map provider from a parent site map**

1. From the parent site map, create a SiteMapNode in the location in
   the navigation structure where you want the child site map to be
   displayed.

   For example, if you are using the default XmlSiteMapProvider class,
   open the Web.sitemap file and add the following SiteMapNode in the
   appropriate location in the hierarchy:

`<siteMapNode provider="SimpleTextSiteMapProvider" />`

> Note
>
> The provider attribute corresponds to the provider's name attribute in the Web.config file.

2. Add the custom site-map provider to the Web.config file by using an add element. The following code adds the custom provider named SimpleTextSiteMapProvider, but maintains XmlSiteMapProvider as the default site-map provider.

   `<configuration>
     <!-- other configuration sections -->
     <system.web>
       <!-- other configuration sections -->
       <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider">
         <providers>
           <add
             name="SimpleTextSiteMapProvider"
         type="Samples.AspNet.SimpleTextSiteMapProvider,Samples.AspNet"
             siteMapFile = "siteMap.txt" />
         </providers>
       </siteMap>
     </system.web>
   </configuration>`